# i see entries in then Azure Function Monitor Logs screen. How do I find them in the Application Insights?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I open the Monitor for my Azure function by clicking on `Functions/FunctionName/Monitor/Logs`.  It says "Connecting to Application Insights..." followed by "Connected".  I run the function and the Monitor screen shows entries generated by `_logger.LogInformation()` call.

[image]

I then try to find those entries (specifically the 3rd line that says `Started orchestration`) in Application Insight, but I can't seem to.

I tried Search, got nothing.
[image]

I also tried querying it, also nothing.
[image]

What am I missing here?

P.S. Using .NET Core 3.1 with Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.9.

P.P.S.  The solution is adding `"logLevel": {"default": "Information"}` to the host.json, like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {"default": "Information"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Click Logs under monitoring and try this query traces
| where (cloud_RoleName == "function name") and (operation_Name == "methodname")
| project severityLevel,message,timestamp, operation_Name,operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| order by timestamp desc
| take 200   - this one works for me. or you can use the logstream option.

Comment: @Aravind I see a bunch of automated recorded entries of `itypeType=Trace`.  What I am not seeing are any entries generated by `_logger.LogInformation`.

Comment: What is the log level set in your host.json? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#log-levels

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT I've left it at defaults like [this](https://pastebin.com/S0XAkfyc).

Comment: can you try this {
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Error",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Aravind "Function": "Error" will suppress information level log from function.

Comment: @Aravind I'll try your suggestion, though as KrishnenduGhosh pointed out it'll suppress things.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT What is the relationship between the Monitor entries (e.g. the entries with the black background in the screenshot) and Application Insights?  Are the Monitor entries actually come from Application Insights?

Comment: The monitor entries are from separate diagnostic listener. Not from application Insights.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT Actually adding `"logLevel": {"default": "Information"}`, like this https://pastebin.com/Pa4qyHXP, did solve the problem.  I was wrong before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the official doc -> logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging), you should specify the log level like below:

```
"logLevel": {"default": "your_log_level"}
```

And if you want to log the `information` level message(for all the log levels, please refer to [Log levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#log-levels)), you should specify it to `Information`:

```
"logLevel": {"default": "Information"}
```